# How to access control on a mdiForm from a child form?

Tags: c#, mdi

I want to show two forms one above the other. Sample form is below. I want a url should be loaded after authenticating for login. Otherwise the fornm behind should be disabled. After Login the form and its controls should be enabled.
I am using MDI for this. One is MDIParent and other as its child.  There is a webbrowser control on a MDI Form . I want to show parent(web browser) and child(login) form together.

[image]

Code behind the login button:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String lusername = txtLogin.Text;
            String lPassword = txtPassword.Text;
            if (lusername.Equals ("admin") && lPassword.Equals ("admin"))
            {
                _Authenticated = true;
                this.Close();
                frmKioskBrowserMain _mainform = new frmKioskBrowserMain();
                _mainform.fnNavigate();


            }
            else 
            {

                lblErrorMessage.Text = "Login Id or Password Mismatch??";

            }
        }
```

fnNavigate is the function on the Parent form

```
public void fnNavigate()
        {
            wbKioskBrowse.Navigate("www.google.com");
        }
```

I searched for a solution but didnt find a suitable one.Also I would like to know if there any other option which I can use??

Comment: Are you getting any error or what ???

Comment: I am not getting any error but the page doesnt load and the controls which are disabled on form load event of Parent form does not get enabled. I am ready to try another way.So if you have some then its welcome

Comment: Okay, Can you do it like this - In **btnLogin_Click** event first create an instance of **frmKioskBrowserMain** form and call its fnNavigate() methode and then instead of closing the form hide it using this line - **this.Hide();**. Just let me know your result / comments.

Comment: The problem is not solved..